# Catch quit blender event in addon

Tags: python

Is there a way to catch the application quit event ?
We have a plugin that runs an xml rpc server and we would like to kill it upon application quit as it keeps running in the background after we quit the blender session.

Thank you,

-H.

Answer (score 1):

one way could be by running Blender from the terminal and just add **&&** at the end.
*NB. not sure on windows though havent try it myself.*

mac:

```
cd /Applications/Blender
./blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender && do_something
```

linux:

```
cd <blender installation directory>
./blender && do_something
```

windows

```
cd c:\<blender installation directory>
blender -and do_something
```

on unix based system the **&&** command does something if the command before has successful, so basically in this case only after you quit blender it will run the second command. on windows **-and** should probably do the same.

you could also probably catch it by launching blender inside python using the **subprocess module**. But haven't try that yet.

Answer (score 0):

the **unregister()** procedure is started when the blender is closed.

Comment: Give an example of use.

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth Please do not introduce any spelling errors with your "macro edits". Might be better to leave it as it is.